# Adding new models to a backbone collection, not replace

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, collections, model

I am trying to add new models to a collection (i'm not saving to the server this time, just doing this in memory). I have the code below:

```
$(function () {

//Model

var Story = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: {
    'title': 'This is the title',
    'description': 'Description',
    'points': 0
  },

  url: '/'

});

//Collection

var Stories = Backbone.Collection.extend({

  model: Story,

  url: '/'

});

//View

var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $('#container'),

  events: {
    'click .inner': 'onClickInner'
  },

  onClickInner: function() {

    this.options.x++;

    this.story.set({
      'title': 'This is my collection test ' + this.options.x,
      'description' : 'this is the description'

    });

    this.stories.add(this.story);

    this.render();

  },

  initialize: function () {

    this.stories = new Stories();
    this.story = new Story();

  },

  render: function(){

      console.log(this.stories);

  }

});

//Initialize App

  var app = new BaseView({
    'x' : 0
  });

});
```

My question is this, for each time 'onClickInner' runs, I want to add a new model to the collection. However, in my code it *replaces* the existing model in the collection. How do I add new models and not replace?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens because you update current model instead of adding new new one. To fix it you have to just execute `add` method on your collection. This method adds passed data as a new model to your collection:

```
this.stories.add({
  'title': 'This is my collection test ' + this.options.x,
  'description' : 'this is the description'
});
```

Comment: This fixes the problem, thanks. I got confused with what the 'set' method on the model was doing. I thought I was creating a new instance of a model and adding it to the collection.

Comment: Wait a minute, if i'm passing data like the above into my collection, what's the point of using the model? Does it not make the model completely redundant as I've written it above?

Comment: If you do not plan to use the model - you can remove it.

Comment: I want to use the model

Comment: In case if you want to have `this.story` model I prepared the demo for you http://jsfiddle.net/vpetrychuk/93cMM/.